# Read Response of POCO HTTPClientRequest

Tags: c++, http, upload, stream, poco-libraries

Hi I am uploading a file using multipart upload in POCO (by sending a the content of file appended with boundaries through a normal POST request). But when I try to read the response as:

```
std::ostream& myOStream = session.sendRequest(req);
// sends the body
myOStream << reqBody;

Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;

// get the response body from server
std::istream& inStream = session.receiveResponse(res);
std::ostringstream outStringStream;
outStringStream << inStream.rdbuf();
std::cout<< outStringStream.str();
```

I get this exception "SSL Connection Unexpectedly Closed" on this line:

```
outStringStream << inStream.rdbuf();
```

Also if i instead try to read the response as:

```
Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream( inStream, outStringStream );
std::cout<< outStringStream.str();
```

I get empty response (No exception in this case).
The server returns a plain text in response. And i am getting it as response if using qt, but not through POCO. Please help me to read the response body. What could be the reason of this exception??

Also, one more thing if I read the response status as res.getStatus() and res.getReason() it returns 200Ok. I dont understand what is the issue with response body.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me you can try.

```
std::istream& rs = _httpClientSession.receiveResponse(response);
memset(_response, 0, RESPONSE_BUFF_SIZE);
rs.read(_response, RESPONSE_BUFF_SIZE-1);
//below code is just to clear the istream
std::streamsize nRead = rs.gcount();
while( !rs.eof() || nRead != 0)
{
    rs.read(_response, RESPONSE_BUFF_SIZE);
    nRead = rs.gcount();
}
```

One more thing, in case of any exception you have to reset http session by invoking _httpClientSession.reset();